# Why won't code runner stop running at the end of my code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

If I run code in VS Code (Python), and literally just make a little print statement, code runner will print the message and then not stop after it reaches the end of the code.. which is one line.

```
print("Hi")
```

will run forever unless I exit manually by doing F1, and then clicking Stop Code Run